# Generic within method declaration

Tags: java, generics

Let's say I have an abstract class called which has this abstract method

```
removeItem(GeneralItem item, String reason);
```

but then in a subclass I have

```
removeItem(SpecificItemThatExtendsGeneralItem item, String reason){ //code }
```

How do I make it so the second removeItem counts as an implementation of the first? e.g

```
removeItem(<? extends GeneralItem> item, String reason);
```

Comment: What would happen if you pass it an OtherSpecificItemThatExtendsGeneralItem?

Comment: That would never happen

Comment: But what if someone else wrote that code and made it happen?

Comment: I'd slap them?  No I don't think that's the corrrect answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A method having signature ...

```
removeItem(SpecificItemThatExtendsGeneralItem item, String reason)
```

... **does not** implement ...

```
removeItem(GeneralItem item, String reason)
```

... because the latter can accept any `GeneralItem`, including those that are not `SpecificItemThatExtendsGeneralItem`.

If you can alter the abstract class, however, then you can make it possible:

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass <T extends GeneralItem> {
    abstract public void removeItem(T item, String reason);
}

class MySubclass extends MyAbstractClass<SpecificItemThatExtendsGeneralItem> {
    @Override
    public void removeItem(SpecificItemThatExtendsGeneralItem item,
            String reason) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

In that case, however, note that type `MySubclass` is then still incompatible with `MyAbstractClass<GeneralItem>`:

```
MyAbstractClass<GeneralItem> = new MySubclass();  // ERROR
```

though it is compatible with `MyAbstractClass<?>` and `MyAbstractClass<SpecificItemThatExtendsGeneralItem>`:

```
MyAbstractClass<?> c = new MySubclass();  // ok
MyAbstractClass<SpecificItemThatExtendsGeneralItem> = new MySubclass(); // ok
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can change base class, you can generalize the first parameter:

```
class BaseClass<T extends GeneralItem> {
    void removeItem(T item, String reason) {
    }
}

class SubClass extends BaseClass<SpecificItemThatExtendsGeneralItem> {
    @Override
    void removeItem(SpecificItemThatExtendsGeneralItem item, String reason) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Subclasses cannot change the type they accept in methods. But you can definitely check if the type is what you expect:

```
removeItem(GeneralItem item, String reason)
{
    if (!(item instanceof SpecificItemThatExtendsGeneralItem))
        throw InvalidArgumentException("Only SpecificItemThatExtendsGeneralItem accepted");
}
```

However, this would not be checked during compilation time, simply because when someone would call

```
abstractClassInstance.removeItem(OtherSpecificItemThatExtendsGeneralItem)
```

the compiler has no way of knowing that this should fail, it does not know which implementation `abstractClassInstance` is actually of.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible.

The method:

```
removeItem(SpecificItemThatExtendsGeneralItem item, String reason){ //code }
```

does not cover all valid ways of calling the method that you're hoping it overrides.  Therefore having a class that (just) implements this method does not fulfil the contract of the parent class.